# Why is my code giving me a "Warning from the last Compilation"?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am trying to modify the compareTo Method so that I can use Comparable Interface here but it's giving me the stated warning. What am I doing wrong ? It shows that there are no syntax errors but as soon as I click on Compile, a small window pops up with a message : " Warnings from last compilation F:\Desktop\PoochyPavy.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details."

The original Code is :

```
   public class PoochyPavy implements Comparable
     {
         public PoochyPavy(int k)
              {
                  value = k;
              }

   public int compareTo(Object nerd) //This method doesn’t follow the normal rules
     {
         PoochyPavy pp = (PoochyPavy) nerd;

         int r;

         if (value = = 6 * pp.value)
        {
           r = 136;
        }
         else
        { 
           r = -137;
        }
          return r;
    }
        …other methods…
     public int value;
    }
```

---

My attempt to modify the code :

```
            public int PoochyPavy(int k)
            {       
                int Value = k;
                return k;
            }
             public int compareTo(Comparable nerd) //This method needs modification
                    {
                    PoochyPavy pp = (PoochyPavy) nerd;
                    int r = 0;

                    if (((Comparable)value).compareTo(6*pp.value)==0)
                        {
                        return r;
                        }   
                    else if (((Comparable)value).compareTo(6*pp.value)<0)
                        {
                        return r-1;
                        }
                    else if (((Comparable)value).compareTo(6*pp.value)>0)
                        {
                        return r+1;
                        }

                    return r;
            }
            //…other methods…
            public int value;
```

Comment: Could you perhaps quote the exact and complete message?  So far what you ask makes no sense.

Comment: Are you modifying the code while debugging? If not: what is the error *exactly*?

Comment: Is `"Warning from the last compilation"` the *entire* thing it says, or is there any additional information provided with the warning?

Comment: Generics were introduced in Java 5. We're now in Java 8, 10 years later. It's time to use them: `PoochyPavy implements Comparable<Poochavy>`

Comment: @ajb - I'm guessing that "Warning from last compilation" is coming from the IDE.  But there's no way to know, given the above useless description.

Comment: It shows that there are no syntax errors but as soon as I click on Compile, a small window pops up with a message : 
" Warnings from last compilation 
F:\Desktop\PoochyPavy.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details."

Comment: @Limbo You're using an untyped `Comparable`, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Your constructor also seem not proper conflicts with function definition.

```
  public class PoochyPavy implements Comparable<PoochyPavy> {
        public PoochyPavy(int k) {
        value = k;
        }

        public int compareTo(PoochyPavy nerd) // This method doesn’t follow the
                          // normal
                          // rules
        {
        PoochyPavy pp = nerd;
        int r = 0;

        if (((Integer) value).compareTo(6 * pp.value) == 0) {
            return r;
        } else if (((Integer) value).compareTo(6 * pp.value) < 0) {
            return r - 1;
        } else if (((Integer) value).compareTo(6 * pp.value) > 0) {
            return r + 1;
        }

        return r;
        }

        public int value;
    }
```